# In swift, is there a way to select a sprite by its name?

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, sprite

I'm new to coding in Swift so I apologize if this is a silly question.

I have a function that creates a series of Sprites. These Sprites move around and change sizes. Through the function, each is given a unique name.

What I would like to do is have their position/animation/size/texture change when a user presses a separate set of sprites. In other words, I need pressing another sprite to call a function which changes the first set of sprites.

However, I'm having trouble doing this. It seems like I can make it work if I hardwire the particular variable name of a sprite in. However, because there are many, they may change over time, and I may want to cycle through many of them hardwiring is not good.

Essentially, I want to be able to select a sprite and animate it once another sprite is touched.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Create a Dictionary from the sprites' `String` name to sprite instances

Comment: make your own Skspritenode (subclass) and override its touchesBegan. make an initializer pram of which sprites the touch will animate. i can make an answer if you need.

Answer (score 1):

You can make your own subclass of SKSpriteNode, then call them from their object name (the name of the variable or let constant). This means you don't have to hardwire, and you can use any sort of logic / function to change the animation or which names of sprites being called / used etc.

In this demo, I make two objects... one a lightbult, another a lightswitch. When you click the lightswitch, the lightbulb will turn on.

Read the comments to learn how to customize this. You can have any object tell any other sprite to play their personal animation:

```
class TouchMeSprite: SKSpriteNode {

    // This is used for when another node is pressed... the animation THIS node will run:
    var personalAnimation: SKAction?

    // This is used when THIS node is clicked... the below nodes will run their `personalAnimation`:
    var othersToAnimate: [TouchMeSprite]?

    override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {

        // Early exit:
        guard let sprites = othersToAnimate else {
            print("No sprites to animate. Error?")
            return
        }

        for sprite in sprites {

            // Early exit:
            if sprite.scene == nil {
                print("sprite was not in scene, not running animation")
                continue
            }

            // Early exit:
            guard let animation = sprite.personalAnimation else {
                print("sprite had no animation")
                continue
            }

            sprite.run(animation)
        }
    }
}
```

---

Here is the GameScene file that shows off the lightswitch and bulb demo:

```
class GameScene: SKScene {

    override func didMove(to: SKView) {

        // Bulb:

        let lightBulb = TouchMeSprite(color: .black, size: CGSize(width: 100, height: 100))
        // Lightbulb will turn on when you click lightswitch:
        lightBulb.personalAnimation = SKAction.colorize(with: .yellow, colorBlendFactor: 1, duration: 0)

        lightBulb.position = CGPoint(x: 0, y: 400)
        lightBulb.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
        addChild(lightBulb)


        // Switch:

        let lightSwitch = TouchMeSprite(color: .gray, size: CGSize(width: 25, height: 50))
        // Lightswitch will turn on lightbulb:
        lightSwitch.othersToAnimate = [lightBulb]

        lightSwitch.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
        lightSwitch.position = CGPoint(x: 0, y: 250)
        addChild(lightSwitch)
    }
}
```